# Pass an update state React Native

Tags: react-native, state, jsx

So I use set state to update a variable in my state, and in the line after I want to use it however it doesn't use the newly updated state but the one before it.

```
this.setState({filter: {startDate : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - days))}})
this.props.fetchGraphEvents(this.props.currentUser, this.props.homeInfo, this.state)
```

in the second line `this.state` I want to use the new state I just updated a line before but it does not work.

Any NPM package you would recommend or open source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state update is async.

You should put the second line in the setState callback

Example:

```
this.SetState({ title: 'New Title'}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.title) // new title is garantee
});
```

Comment: I did this and it did not work                                                                         ```this.setState({filter: {startDate : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - days))}}, () =>{
                    this.props.fetchGraphEvents(this.props.currentUser, this.props.homeInfo, this.state)
                    })```

Comment: If the state values are updated has you wish in the callback...the problem is somewhere else my friend